# Network getting suspended and Doze state in Android 7.0 OS

Tags: android

How to tackle the problem of Doze mode. My App, having the feature of downloads after using while it stopped network calls.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: It's not a problem of the Doze mode, but yours. Describe in more details what do you want to achieve

Comment: check job scheduler

Comment: Thanks but, After updating the OS to 7.0 from 6.0, I have noticed sometimes my App doesn't communicate to the server. It seems network is getting suspended (DOZE mode or App getting standby).  As our application is having the feature of large file downloads from the server. After some %, the downloads stopped in between. But, after some time it starts to download even though a user is using the App or connected to the network.
As per my understanding, the Android Device latest enabled Doze mode for the battery power saver.

Comment: As per my understanding, the Android Device latest enabled Doze mode for the battery power saver. As per mentioned in the developer console.  https://developer.android.com/…/monitorin…/doze-standby.html
But, when I have checked Doze state it always telling me the NORMAL_INTERACTIVE using below Code.
final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); DozeState state= pm.isDeviceIdleMode() ? DozeState.DOZE_TURNED_ON_IDLE : pm.isInteractive() ? DozeState.NORMAL_INTERACTIVE : DozeState.NORMAL_NON_INTERACTIVE;